# Using Play 2 framework drop down list with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, playframework

I am new to play framework so please bear with me. Can some one explain to me how to access an item selected in a play 2 framework drop down list, using a jQuery function?

For example:

```
    <select class = "selectone">
@for(gesture <- gesturesList){
  <div class = "gesture" >  <option value = @gesture.id>
        @gesture.getName()
  </option>
  </div>} 
</select>
```

The above drop down list is populated by the following function:

```
public static Result gesture()
  {
  List <Gesture> gcet = Gesture.find.orderBy("name asc").findList();
  return ok(views.html.train.render(gcet)); 
}
```

I want to access the selected item using jQuery or maybe JavaScript. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood, that's nothing to do with Play, it's pure Jquery:

```
 //uses a class selector to get the selected value in the dropdown
 $(".selectone").val();
```

That said, you are adding a `div` in your select, it shouldn't be like that. Your code should be:

```
  <select class = "selectone">
  @for(gesture <- gesturesList){
      <option value = @gesture.id>
        @gesture.getName()
      </option>
  } 
  </select>
```

Comment: I tried ur suggestion pere was able to get the value. but then I am only able to retrieve the value of the first object in the drop down list. Even after highlighting another object the value does not change. for example if we have arc , bet and cain  in the list, I can only get the value of arc but cannot get bet or cain even after selecting them from the list. Any suggestion with that.